# groupby and mean returning NaN

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to use groupby to group by symbol and return the average of prior high volume days using pandas.

I create my data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "date": ['2022-01-01', '2022-01-02', '2022-01-03', '2022-01-04', '2022-01-05', '2022-01-06'],
    "symbol": ['ABC', 'ABC', 'ABC', 'AAA', 'AAA', 'AAA'],
    "change": [20, 1, 2, 3, 50, 100],
    "volume": [20000000, 100, 3000, 500, 40000000, 60000000],
})
```

Filter by high volume and change:

```
high_volume_days = df[(df['volume'] >= 20000000) & (df['change'] >= 20)]
```

Then I get the last days volume (this works):

```
high_volume_days['previous_high_volume_day'] = high_volume_days.groupby('symbol')['volume'].shift(1)
```

But when I try to calculate the average of all the days per symbol:

```
high_volume_days['avg_volume_prior_days'] = df.groupby('symbol')['volume'].mean()
```

I am getting NaNs:

```
         date symbol  change    volume  previous_high_volume_day  avg_volume_prior_days
0  2022-01-01    ABC      20  20000000                       NaN                    NaN
4  2022-01-05    AAA      50  40000000                       NaN                    NaN
5  2022-01-06    AAA     100  60000000                40000000.0                    NaN
```

What am I missing here?

Desired output:

```
       date symbol  change    volume  previous_high_volume_day  avg_volume_prior_days
0  2022-01-01    ABC      20  20000000                       NaN                    20000000
4  2022-01-05    AAA      50  40000000                       NaN                    40000000
5  2022-01-06    AAA     100  60000000                40000000.0                    50000000
```

Comment: can you provide desired output?

Comment: I have provided the desired output, thanks Kim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
high_volume_days['avg_volume_prior_days'] = high_volume_days.groupby('symbol', sort=False)['volume'].expanding().mean().droplevel(0)
```

`high_volume_days`

```
    date        symbol  change  volume  previous_high_volume_day    avg_volume_prior_days
0   2022-01-01  ABC     20      20000000    NaN                     20000000.0
4   2022-01-05  AAA     50      40000000    NaN                     40000000.0
5   2022-01-06  AAA     100     60000000    40000000.0              50000000.0
```

Comment: Appreciate you!! And everyone else who helped! :)

Answer (score 1):

Index misalignment: `high_volume_days` is indexed by integers. The `df.groupby(...)` is indexed by the symbol.

Use `merge` instead:

```py
high_volume_days = pd.merge(
    high_volume_days,
    df.groupby("symbol")["volume"].mean().rename("avg_volume_prior_days"),
    left_on="symbol",
    right_index=True,
)
```

Comment: Thanks Code different. I must be confused, I would have thought AAA volume would be 50000000? As (60000000 + 40000000) / 2 is 50000000? I have updated the OP with the required output. I should have mentioned that to begin with - my bad

Answer (score 1):

`df.groupby('symbol')['volume'].mean()` returns:

```
symbol
AAA    33333500.0
ABC     6667700.0
Name: volume, dtype: float64
```

which is an aggregation of each group to a single value. Note that the groups (symbol) are the index of this series. When you try to assign it back to `high_volume_days`, there is an index misalignment.

Instead of an aggregation (`.mean()` is equivalent to `.agg("mean")`), you should use a transformation: `.transform("mean")`.

==== EDIT ====

Instead of the mean for all values, you're looking for the mean "thus far". You can typically do that using `.expanding().mean()`, but since you're reassigning back to a column in `high_volume_days`, you need to either drop the level that contains the symbols, or use a lambda:

```
high_volume_days.groupby('symbol')['volume'].expanding().mean().droplevel(0)
# or
high_volume_days.groupby('symbol')['volume'].transform(lambda x: x.expanding().mean())
```

Comment: hey mate thank you for your help! Shouldn't the mean of AAA volume be 50000000? And ABC NaN as there is only one day?

Comment: You're calling the groupby on your original `df`, not on `high_volume_days`, so I wasn't sure which one you intended :) @a7dc

Comment: Ah my bad, Apologies, I'm a noob lol. I have updated the OP with the desired output (I should have done that from the beginning!)